# Проблема с отображением картинки при обновлении

Tags: html

Есть сайт, где размещены логотипы. При обновлении страницы логотипы на секунду становятся огромные, и к тому же не такие, как я хочу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через секунду они опять возвращяются на место.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите так:

```
img, png {
   width: //50px;
   height: //50px;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Дело не в размерах,а скрипт слайдера срабатывает с опозданием.Как это исправить?

Comment: если скрипт срабатывает позже, попробуйте переместить его снизу вверх, поставить внутри `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

загрузить логотипы сразу нужного размера. но вообще вопрос про "подземный стук".

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0D7G4XU.png        Вот что стало после загрузки логотипа нужного размера.Это появляется на 1 секунду,и снова все становится на свои места

Comment: такое ощущение, что стили css подгружаются с задержкой. посмотрите исходный код страницы, `<style>...</style>` наверное где-то в самом низу?

Comment: я понял в чем дело.А дело в том что я каждую страницу разделил на хидер и футер.Тоесть каждая страница загружается через 1 хидер и футер.На футере находятся скрипты страниц так как там "</body>".И вот на этой странице(где логотипы) есть слайдер.Тоесть логотипы крутятся слайдером.Так вот,почему то скрипт слайдера в футере загружается с запозданием.Почему?

Comment: скрипты слайдера обычно так себя ведут :) от реализации зависит. скорее всего, даже если скрипт загружается сразу, начать выполняться он может только после события "загрузка всей страницы"

Comment: и это как я понял никак не исправить?